# Mudar caminho do BD Sql Compact no Setting.Designer.cs C#

Tags: c#

Fiz uma aplicação no qual o arquivo do sql compact (.sdf) estará alocado num PC da rede e eu queria ter a opção de mudar o caminho do banco de dados sempre que eu quiser. Para que todos os DatagridView vejam este novo caminho, acredito que eu teria que mudar o caminho no arquivo Settings.Designer.cs onde tenho a seguinte linha:

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database.sdf")]
```

estou certo?

O problema é que estou tentando por no lugar do #|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf# uma variável "global" onde tem armazenado o caminho do arquivo

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source='" + globalinfos.bancoDeDados + "'")]
```

Porém ele me dá o seguinte erro:

> Error 1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type  D:\PROJETOS\HMS\HMS 30-05-2017-NOVA FASE - V2\HMS\hms\hms\hms\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs   29  68  hms

Comment: É exatamente isso que o erro diz, naquele lugar você só pode colocar uma expressão **constante**.

Comment: Aliás, pq você precisa alterar o caminho deste arquivo?